# Keycloak release version before 4.8.3

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak 3.2.0.final and want to upgrade to the latest version 8.0.0.
But I see recently keycloak has removed all the version before 4.8.3 on its website.

I want to do step by step upgrade so that i am not breaking the database with the missing releases in between with contains database changes. I tried to find the older released versions on internet but couldn't find it.

Can someone help me with finding the older versions of keyclaok? or any better way to upgrade keycloak to latest version?

Comment: You can always pick the source code for the versions you want from Github, compile and run them locally.

Comment: Or you can use Docker images - https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/tags older versions are still available on Docker Hub.